# Date picker isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a to and from date displayed on my website. But they are below each other and i want them side by side. I have used display:inline but it still hasn't worked. I also have a date picker on both input fields but it only works on one. Not sure why at all. And the date picker that is displaying is displaying below other input boxes so you can only partially see it. Does anyone know how to fix these problems. Would be very grateful for any help.

HTML

```
<h3> Set your holiday dates </h3> 

    <p class="date"> Date From: </p>
    <input type="text" id="datepickerdoc"> 
    <p class="date">Date To: </p> 
    <input type="text" id="datepickerdoc">
```

UPDATED

```
 <h3> Search for your hotel you booked </h3> 
 <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="searchHotel" class="form-control"/>
                <a href="#Hotels"><span class="input-group-addon" value="search" id="submit" name="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span></a>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepickerdoc").datepicker();
});
```

CSS

```
.date{
    display:inline;
}


#searchHotel {
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: It only works on one because you have 2 elements with the same `ID` which is not valid. `ID`s need to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS won't work as you are targetting the p tag but the datepicker is not inside the p tag and you have the same ID used twice for the datepicker but could use a class for that:

Try something like:

```
<h3> Set your holiday dates </h3> 

    <span class="dpWrapper"><p class="date"> Date From: </p>
    <input type="text" class="datepickerdoc"> </span>
    <span class="dpWrapper"><p class="date">Date To: </p> 
    <input type="text" class="datepickerdoc"> </span>
```

CSS:

```
.dpWrapper {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepickerdoc").datepicker();
});
```

Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cfy053aw/1/

Comment: I tried this and it is making the input fields go side by side, but now the date picker isn't working

Comment: Did it work before? I assume you are including jQuery and the relevant datepicker library etc?

Comment: Yea I used the answer before and changed the class so they read datepickerto and datepickerfrom and they were working perfectly before I added a span class to them

Comment: What datepicker are you using?

Comment: See my answer for a jsfiddle of this working using that library etc

Comment: Yes this works, thank you, however it is still below the search input field. i have added the html to my question if you want to have a look. Not sure why the date picker is being displayed below the input field

Comment: Your code addition does not make sense - post your whole code and show where each sits relative to the others along with all relevant CSS

Comment: all of the code is there now, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166357/discussion-between-bhttoan-and-ol12-9).

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the same id (datepickerdoc). So only one of them gets set by the code. One solution would be to set them both to a certain class, then change the query to select that class instead of the id.

Answer (score 0):

Change the elements from `id="datepickerdoc"` to `class="datepickerdoc"` to fix the issue with only one opening. `ID`s need to be unique.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".datepickerdoc").datepicker();
});
```

```css
.date{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.4/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.4/datepicker.js"></script>
<h3> Set your holiday dates </h3> 

<p class="date">
  Date From:
  <input type="text" class="datepickerdoc">
</p>
<p class="date">
  Date To:
  <input type="text" class="datepickerdoc">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although when I change the css it still is displaying below each other

Comment: You need to wrap the p and input tags inside the inline-block and not just the p tag

Comment: @OL12_9 make sure the `input` is encased in the `p` tag as well. Answer updated